# Symfony2: How to override a single service from the bundle, with my own class?

Tags: symfony, service, dependency-injection

This seems like it should be the most basic thing to do, but I cannot find any info on it. If bundle defines multiple services, how can I override single service with my own?

For example if I have one bundle with defined service, which is being used by another services of that bundle, because it implements certain interface:

```
myapp_user.user.factory:
    class: MyApp\UserBundle\User\UserFactory
    arguments: ["@myapp_user.user.config_manager"]
```

I would like to override this service with my own, like that:

```
myapp_user.user.factory:
    class: MyApp2\UserBundle\User\UserFactory
    arguments: ["@myapp_user.user.config_manager"]
```

I thought that it should be very simple, isn't the whole container idea about - being able to easily switch services/dependencies? However I cannot find any information on it. There is information about creating "parent" bundle, and overriding "file with definition of services", but nothing about single services. Am I missing something? I really don't want to use "parent bundle" thing for replacing just one service with my own.

Comment: It should work, but you have to to declare your custom service after the first, your bundle with your override must be loaded after the first one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Raphaël Malié I figured out the answer. The problem was indeed with the order of imports of files with declared services. Silly me :) .